# Row change notifications in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, database-design, architecture, azure-sql-database, scalability

We would like to have the following capability, where users can make modifications to a specific table (create or update rows), while users can request all the changes made after a specific change, receives the changes in order, so last change can be used for a subsequent call.

Basically we want to mimic a MessageQueue's change notification but instead of message-push, via a pull-based service endpoint.

We also have a technical requirement, to use Azure SQL for DB, and a webserver to handle user requests (REST API). This is how we defined the problem so far:

- Each row has a ChangeID property, which is globally monotonically increasing, whenever a change is made for the row (insert, update)

  - To ensure ever-increasing property, we would use a SEQUENCE to generate ChangeIDs
  - Having no gaps in used ChangeIDs is NOT a requirement
- Each Update and Insert happens in transactions, along with changing the ChangeID property

The general usage would be read-heavy (90% read, 10% write). We'd like to have a solution which is scalable and has good performance: a read/write concurrency model as parallel as possible, while we also expect rollbacks for transactions.

Is it ok to use SEQUENCE here? [SEQUENCEs are not part of transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15)

The worst problem, that we want to avoid is that a client does not get notified about a change.
E.g.:

- T0: Client GET Changes (from: 5):

  - Recieves ChangeIDs: 6, 8, 12
  - Client updates its ChangeCursor to 12
- T1: Server finishes updating, table is updated with ChangeIDs: 9, 15, 16
- T2: Client GET Changes (from: 12):

  - Receives ChangeIDs: 15, 16
  - Error, client will never be notified of ChangeID 9